# Set gradient to Canvas.drawtext

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, view

I'm an android developer. i'm working on a game and i need to change my letters style as below picture. How to add gradient in canvas as in the picture [image: letters]

this code add gradient but to whole view. if letters at bottom they are white if letters at top they are black

```
Paint p = new Paint();
// start at 0,0 and go to 0,max to use a vertical
// gradient the full height of the screen.
p.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
canvas.drawPaint(p);
```

Comment: yes i did that and what i get is the whole view is affected. Letters get affected only if they are in certain part of view. i want only letter to be affected by the gradient

Comment: Shade can do lot of things but i'm just a bigginer. The code i have there affect whole view.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
class V extends View {
    private String text = "Back To The Future";
    private Paint paint;
    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(32);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, paint.getTextSize() + bounds.top, 0, paint.getTextSize(), Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, TileMode.MIRROR);
        paint.setShader(shader);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, paint.getTextSize(), paint);
    }
}
```